# How to get the number of the neurons in the fully-connected layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I saw an example code about a CNN with tensorflow, but I can't understand why the fully-connected layer is (3456, 784), can you tell how to get these number from the convolutional Layer. The input is an 80*100 image and 4 input channels.

Here is the code.

```
def convolutional_neural_network(input_image):
    weights = {'w_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([8, 8, 4, 32])),
               'w_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4, 4, 32, 64])),
               'w_conv3':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 3, 64, 64])),
               'w_fc4':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3456, 784])),
               'w_out':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, output]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32])),
              'b_conv2':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64])),
              'b_conv3':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64])),
              'b_fc4':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784])),
              'b_out':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output]))}

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(input_image, weights['w_conv1'], strides = [1, 4, 4, 1], padding = "VALID") + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, weights['w_conv2'], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = "VALID") + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv2, weights['w_conv3'], strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = "VALID") + biases['b_conv3'])
    conv3_flat = tf.reshape(conv3, [-1, 3456])
    fc4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(conv3_flat, weights['w_fc4']) + biases['b_fc4'])

    output_layer = tf.matmul(fc4, weights['w_out']) + biases['b_out']
    return output_layer
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the size of your input?

Comment: The input is an 80*100 image and 4 input channels.

Comment: Okay, read up [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/). It is advisable to have a little background on CNNs before you decide to go ahead and use them.

Answer (score 3):

The number of neurons in a fully connected layer is *in no way related* to the number of units in the previous layer. You could even put a fully connected with 1 neuron after a layer with 10000 neurons.

The term 'fully connected' means that you connect *every* neuron from the previous layer to the *current* layer. So there is NO dimensionality requirement in there.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733971/convolutional-layer-to-fully-connected-layer-in-cnn/42740476#42740476).

Answer (score 0):

Your number of *neurons* in that layer is actually `784`, and it is entirely your choice at that point, you can set it to 1 or 10000, it will only change the next layer's weights shape.

`(3456, 784)` is the shape of the *weight matrix* associated to the layer, which is the matrix shape needed to get an output vector of size `784` from a vector input of size `3456` (which is the size of your previous layer `conv3_flat`).

`3456` is the size of the `conv3_flat`, which is the number of neurons in `conv3`, which is this layer's `width*height*depth`. You can get it by considering you input image size (as a tuple), dividing it element-wise by the stride (as a tuple; and with padding=valid it should be integral division) at each convolution or pooling layer, and then multiplying the resulting width, height, and the depth (i.e. number of channels) of your last convolutional layer (64 here).

I also suggest you make sure you understand the theory behing CNNs before trying to use them, @Coldspeed's link seems to be a good one.